# Why should someone use decimal expansion of a real number when that decimal expansion is ITSELF a real number?

Tags: real-analysis, cardinals

EDIT: Is the cornell proof incomplete? Since it doesn't account for the two possible decimal expansions of a real number. For example, it says 1/2 = .5 but doesn't account for .49999999...

I'm looking at these two proofs - one from Cornell and one from Berkeley (example 3).

https://courses.cs.cornell.edu/cs2800/wiki/index.php/Proof:The_set_of_reals_is_uncountable

[https://math.berkeley.edu/~arash/55/2_5.pdf](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Earash/55/2_5.pdf)

I understand Cornell's proof, but I'm confused about the Berkeley proof. Why does the Berkeley proof consider the decimal representation of real numbers between 0 and 1 and not just the real number itself, since it's already in decimal form (since it's between 0 and 1). Doesn't this just add potential holes in the argument, since there are either 1 or 2 possible decimal expansion forms?

I'm not comfortable with the real numbers or decimal expansions, so there's a good chance I'm missing something. My friend also wrote a proof that uses decimal expansion, but I'm not sure why. Basically, why should someone use decimal expansion? Is it because 5 is a real number but we want to represent it in decimal form so the decimal expansion of 5 is 5.00000... and 4.99999....? IN SHORT: Why should someone use decimal expansion of a real number when that decimal expansion is ITSELF a real number?

My friends proof:

Proceed by contradiction. Suppose there exists a surjection $f: \mathbb N \mapsto \mathbb R$. Consider the possible decimal expansions of $f(n)$ for any $n \in \mathbb N$; (there may be multiple). Consider the $n$th place after the decimal point, and let $S_n$ be the set of integers that appears in this $n$th place after the decimal point among the possible decimal expansions of $f(n)$.

Lemma: First fixing $n$ and $f$th, $S_n$ has at most two elements (give proof)

Now, for each $n$, pick $0 \leq a_n \leq 9$ an integer not in $S_n$ (can do that as $|S_n| \leq 2$). Consider a = $0.a_1a_2a_3\cdots$, i.e. the real number with decimal expansion given by $a_1$ in the tenths place, $a_2$ in the hundredths place, etc. Then $a \notin Im(f)$, i.e. $a \neq f(a)$ for any $n \in \mathbb N$ (give proof), so $f$ is not a surjection.

Comment: decimal expansion is a *representation* of a real number

Comment: "since it's already in decimal form".  Say the number in question is $\frac1{\sqrt2}$.  How is that already in decimal form?  Why not binary form?  In fact it's not in any "form" at all, it's just a number.

Comment: @saulspatz that cleared is up. but doesn't that mean the cornell proof is incomplete, since it doesn't account for the two possible decimal expansions of a real number. for example, it says 1/2 = .5 but doesnt account for .49999999...

Comment: @saulspatz also, what's the decimal expansion of an integer like 3? Is it 3.0000... and 2.9999...

Comment: Either representation is correct.  Any terminating decimal has two decimal expansions.  As to the Cornell proof, there's no need to account for $.4999\dots.$  They're counting real numbers, not decimal expansions.  It would be possible to count the number of infinite sequences of the digits $0,1,\dots,9$, but since we already know that real numbers are uncountable, and there are more digit sequences, the digit sequences are uncountable also.

Comment: @saulspatz Yeah, so that's where I'm confused. For the cornell proof, if f(i) = 1/sqrt(2), wouldn't they use decimal expansion to write it in decimal form?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  I don't understand exactly where you're still confused.

Comment: @saulspatz so then the cornell proof does use decimal expansions, right? since if f(i) = 1/sqrt(2), they're writing it in decimal form

Comment: Yes, they are using decimal expansions.

Comment: @saulspatz sorry to ask again but then wdym by "They're counting real numbers, not decimal expansions"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115243/discussion-between-saulspatz-and-beginner).

Answer (score 1):

A decimal expansion is a **sequence** $u=(u_n)_{n>0} \in \{0;...;9\}^{\mathbb{N}^{>0}}$. You have a function $\sigma: \{0;...;9\}^{\mathbb{N}^{>0}} \rightarrow [0,1]$ which sends a decimal expansion $u$ to the sum $\sum \limits_{n>0}\frac{u_n}{10^n}$. Say that a decimal expansion $u$ is the decimal expansion of a number $x$ if $\sigma(u)=x$. Then it is known that each number $x\in [0,1]$ has exactly one or exactly two decimal representations: it has only one if it is not decimal or if $x \in \{0,1\}$, and it has two otherwise.

Writing a number in decimal form is not a mathematical statement, but an informal way to say "considering / computing the decimal expansion" of said number.